# Emacs - represent JSON-like structures

Tags: emacs, elisp

What would be the canonical way for emacs to represent JSON-like structures, or nested hashmaps ?

I have a structure with approximately 25 top-level keys. Each key has no more than a sub-key (ie. the value is another key/value element). Some of the final values are FIFO arrays.

I stated to model this using `hash-map`, but it feels cumbersome. Now I just stumbled upon `assoc-lists`, what would be the most appropriate in my case ?

*Note :* I intend to replicate `parinfer` in elisp, [`this part`](https://github.com/shaunlebron/parinfer/blob/master/lib/parinfer.js#L80-L129) for now, and learn elisp at the same time.

Comment: Depends on the shape and size of your JSON-like data, and what you plan to do with it. You have hash maps, association lists (alists), property lists (plists), etc., each with its own properties. "JSON-like structure" is not specific enough. The question is still too broad, IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `assoc-lists`, which are the Emacs standard way of representing a map/dictionary/table. You see them in a lot of places: `auto-mode-alist`, `minor-mode-alist`, `interpreter-mode-alist`, etc. `hash-map` is only meant for speed, when you have 1000+ entries.

There's even an official way to convert JSON to an `assoc-list`:

```
(json-read-from-string "{\"foo\": {\"bar\": 5}}")
=> ((foo (bar . 5)))
```